# Running cpu use average over past 1 hour sampled every minute using performance counters

Tags: c#, .net, statistics, cpu-usage, performancecounter

I am trying to calculate the running average of overall CPU usage (sampled every minute or less) over the past hour.

So the algorithm should ideally read the cpu entry every minute (or less) and give me the average of the entries taken over the past running 60 minute time window. Current average counters or %counters give me an all-time average not the running average.

What counter/ custom technique would be best suited for this purpose?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2195680/calculating-averages-with-performance-counters) question is quite similar but not the same. Since it is not deleting entries from the sampling history that are more than 60 mins old

Answer (score 0):

Check the following: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.performancecounter?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8

There is even an example looking very similar to what you are trying to do:

> The example creates categories, sets up counters, collects data from the counters, and calls the CounterSampleCalculator class to interpret the performance counter data. The intermediate and final results are displayed in the console window. For additional examples of other performance counter types, see the PerformanceCounterType enumeration.

Comment: This doesnt quite do the trick since it provides no API to delete sample values older than an hour while calculating the average